# Control.Invoke from same thread where the form is running

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

In C#, is there any problem using Control.Invoke to change a property of a Control from the same thread where the form is running?

I know it would be best using `Control.Property = value`, but I'd like to know which are the consequences of using Control.Invoke instead.

Example:

Using this:

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new delegate {Label1.Text = "Hello"});
    }
}
```

Instead of this:

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a property InvokeRequired. You should call this first, to know if you need Invoke or not.

Comment: Just overhead of doing invoke.  It should work fine, but WHY?

Comment: According to the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,7241): "It is an error to call this on the same thread that the control belongs to." (This is on `Invoke(delegate,object[])` but we can see that `Invoke(delegate)` just delegates to that method)

Comment: You lose -100 elegance points for having no idea what thread your code runs on.  Making proving that the code is thread-safe very hard to do, never a good property of threaded code.  That's all, the overhead is pretty minimal.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - the comments might say that, but the code does not seem to enforce it.  Of course just because it works today (I tried it) doesn't mean it will.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it somewhat confusingly goes on to say "There are five functions on a control that are safe to call from **any thread**:  GetInvokeRequired, **Invoke**, BeginInvoke, EndInvoke and CreateGraphics." (my emphasis of course)

Comment: Having just debugged an issue around this, I will mention that an Invoke() from the same thread does NOT run the code synchronously as you would expect, but rather queues the delegate and effectively put the current method into a DoEvents() loop. Any previous messages will process first.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Invoke(new Action(
    delegate()
    {
        label2.Text = "Test";
    }));
```

or

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
    delegate()
    {
        label2.Text = "Test";
    }));
```

Comment: @Blorgbeard you don' talk about your command. I hope that want to help your question!! if you don't help about my answer, Upload your question in more detail.